# python reduce function returns false for check same element in a list

Tags: python

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x == y, [2,2,2,2,2])
False
```

I want to check every element in a list if they are the same and I thought this would do the trick, apprarently not. Can you some explain why it returns false and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

If you look [at the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce),

> `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calculates `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`

So, a smaller example `reduce(lambda x,y: x == y, [2,2,2])` would be `(2==2)==2` would be False

Answer (score 1):

The first application of the lambda function is `2 == 2`, which yields `True`. The next application is `True == 2`, which is `False`. Finally, the last two applications of the lambda do `False == 2`, which is again `False.`

If the list has length >= 1, I would do:

```
all(lst[0] == x for x in lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the lambda function you gives, x is the accumulated value, and y is each element in the array.

1. x: 2, y: 2, lambda returns True
2. x: True, y: 2, lambda returns False
3. ...
4. x: False, y: 2, lambda returns False

To fix it, you could simple use `len(set(arr)) == 1` to see if there is only one unique element in this array.

Comment: Why did you link to JS code?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this would be to check if the number of distinct elements in the list is 1

```
len(set([2,2,2,2,2]))==1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print the value of `x` and `y` during the reduce operation:

```
def f(x,y):
    print 'x=',x,'y=',y
    return x==y

print reduce(f, [2,2,2,2,2])
```

it outputs :

> x= 2 y= 2
>   x= True y= 2 #x contains True because it is the result of (x==y) hence 2==2
>   x= False y= 2 #x contains False because it is the result of (x==y) hence True==2
>   x= False y= 2 #same reason
>   False

To avoid this behavior you could specify an initial element that contains the result of the reduction and the value of the previous element.

Something like

```
def f(x,y):
    print 'x=',x, 'y=', y
    return (x[1]==None or (x[0] and x[1]==y), y)

print reduce(f, [2,2,2,2,2], (True,None))
```

This time it outputs :

> x= (True, None) y= 2
>   x= (True, 2) y= 2
>   x= (True, 2) y= 2
>   x= (True, 2) y= 2
>   x= (True, 2) y= 2
>   (True, 2)

**In a compressed lambda form it boils down to:**

```
reduce(lambda x,y: (x[1]==None or (x[0] and x[1]==y), y), list, (True,None))[0]
```

Try it

```
l = [2,2,2,2,2]
print reduce(lambda x,y: (x[1]==None or (x[0] and x[1]==y), y), l, (True,None))[0]
l = [2,2,3,2,2]
print reduce(lambda x,y: (x[1]==None or (x[0] and x[1]==y), y), l, (True,None))[0]
```

> True
>   False